# Split Full Name into First Name and Last Name fields Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, concatenation

I have this query to retrieve the First Name out of the Full_Name field.

```
SELECT Employee_Table.Full_Name, Left([Full_Name],InStr([Full_Name]," ")-1) AS First_Name
FROM Employee_Table;
```

It works fine,

However, I tried to change the query to get the Last Name into the Last_Name field by changing the query to this one but it did not work. Please Help

```
SELECT Employee_Table.Full_Name, Right([Full_Name],InStr([Full_Name]," ")+1) AS Last_Name
FROM Employee_Table;
```

I would like to have only one query that pulls the information and not two separate ones.

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second query, you are pulling from the end of the string, but the length is from the beginning.  Oops.  The function that you want is `MID()` rather than `RIGHT()`:

```
SELECT Employee_Table.Full_Name, Left([Full_Name],InStr([Full_Name]," ")-1) AS First_Name,
       mid([Full_Name],InStr([Full_Name]," ")+1) as Last_Name
FROM Employee_Table;
```

Comment: You are awesome.  Thanks a lot I will remember that for the future.